# Need to write data in Excel which has links to another excel workbook Using R

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I'm trying to write data into an Macro enabled file which has links to another excel file. But when I try to write data using openxlsx package the excel files gets corrupted, below is my code:

```
wb <-loadWorkbook("C:/Test/Excel.xlsm")
writeData(wb,df,sheet="sheet1",startRow=2)
saveWorkbook(wb,"C:/Test/Excel.xlsm", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I have tried xlsx package too but it doesn't support macro enabled file.

Comment: Hi, I did several works integrating R and Excel VBA. I was not satisfied by any package, they are or memory expensive or they are not reliable. In my opinion the best solution is that you simply write a plain csv file, then write VBA code to import the data from the csv

Comment: You mean I should write a Macro in Excel to write data from 1 excel to other?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Probably is not what you wanted, but trust me, It's the easier solution .                                                                                                 Set wbCsv = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=percorso, UpdateLinks:=False, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)

Comment: Is Workbooks.Open() a function in openxlsx?

Comment: no, It's a VBA function